# How does KLEE model memory?

Tags: symbolic-computation, klee

http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dsl11/klee-doxygen/overview.html

I'm trying to model memory for binaries and so I would like to see how KLEE handles it. However, I am having trouble understanding the explanation from the overview.

Can I get an easier explanation, and possibly a simple example of how this would be done?